# How do I change the color of the outputs of the bupaR packages (e.g. a process map)?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to change the color of the plots that bupaR and adjacent packages output. They always use a blue color. So far I have managed to recolor the nodes of a process_map, but I would also like to color the edges and all other plots.

Further, the processmonitR/edeaR package creates dashboards, which I would like to recolor. The colors seem to be hardcoded (see [here](https://github.com/gertjanssenswillen/edeaR/blob/master/R/plot.activity_frequency.R))

Example output with default colors:

```
library(dplyr)
library(bupaR)
library(shiny)

patients %>% process_map

patients %>% process_map(type = frequency("absolute", color_scale = "Oranges"))

patients %>% precedence_matrix %>% plot

patients %>% plotly_trace_explorer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scale_fill = scale_fill_discrete(h = c(0, 310) + 50, l = 50, c = 150)`. Check the documentation for function arguments.